# Lambda function running code first run but not subsequent runs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I have a Node.js Lambda function that during the inital run ran fine, however during the subsequent runs - 1 minute interval - it is completing in about 1.5ms and not running my code at all other than outputting finished - the `console.log` in my `then` block.

What would the reason for this be?

```
module.exports.perf = function(event, context, callback) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  
  let input = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);

  const point1 = new Point('elapsedTime')
    .tag(input.monitorID, 'monitorID')
    .floatField('elapsedTime', input.perf_value)
  writeApi.writePoint(point1)
  writeApi
  .close()
  .then(() => {
      console.log('FINISHED ... ')
  })
  .catch(e => {
      console.error(e)
      if (e instanceof HttpError && e.statusCode === 401) {
      console.log('Run ./onboarding.js to setup a new InfluxDB database.')
      }
      console.log('\nFinished ERROR')
  })
  return
};
```

EDIT**

````
const writeApi = new InfluxDB({url: InfluxURL, token}).getWriteApi(org, bucket, 'ms')```
````

Comment: You should not `return` from the function before the asynchronous code has completed.

Comment: @Bergi So it should not be async since I don't have async anywhere in there. And I don't think that would explain why it would run once but not after that.

Comment: The `writeApi` thing definitely appears to be asynchronous, as it returns a promise.

Comment: @Bergi Okay I will test it out and see but I am to confident that is it since the problem doesn't appear to point to async

Comment: @Bergi Removed that and no luck. The lambda hasn't been running since just after I posted this question, I started the schedule up again and it ran once fine, the second and third time it did the issue which I brought up in the OP of not running my code on subsequent runs. This does not seem to be an async issue but a different one related to how lambda is processing my code.

Comment: You're saying it *does* run the `console.log('FINISHED ... ')`? Then it's not like your code is not running. However, maybe your `writeApi` is broken. Can you post its code, please?

Comment: @Bergi Yes the console.log with finished does run, I can't post the writeApi code since it is not my code and is from a public package. See my edit for more info

Comment: Ok. So what exactly does not run? The elapsed time value is not written into the influxdb?

Comment: @Bergi The only thing that seems to run is the finished console.log  Correct, the data isn't being written to influxdb

Comment: @Bergi Any chance you might have an idea on how to solve this? I've had zero luck with figuring it out.

Comment: No idea. The code appears to be fine. The only thing that might be worth investigating is whether `writePoint` needs to be awaited before calling `close`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming up with a solution thanks to someone elsewhere online and the result was changing `.close()` to `.flush()` in the following code

```
writeApi
  .flush() # used to be .close()
  .then(() => {
      console.log('FINISHED ... ')
  })
```